# Convert .Net dll to jar file

Tags: .net, dll, jar

I have a .net dll file compiled for windows. I need to convert it to a .jar file with the same functionality for android.
Is there a way to convert it to an executable .jar file?

I tried Com4j for this.  But it threw an exception.

> C:\Users\Name\Desktop\com>java -jar tlbimp.jar -o output -p mypackage Maths.dll
>
> ```
> Exception in thread "main" com4j.
>
> ExecutionException: com4j.ComException: 80029c4
> a LoadTypeLib failed : Error loading type library/DLL. : .\com4j.cpp:395
>         at com4j.ComThread.execute(ComThread.java:203)
>         at com4j.Task.execute(Task.java:25)
>         at com4j.COM4J.loadTypeLibrary(COM4J.java:322)
>         at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Lib.getLibid(Lib.java:90)
>         at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Driver.addLib(Driver.java:38)
>         at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Main.doMain(Main.java:123)
>         at com4j.tlbimp.driver.Main.main(Main.java:56)
> Caused by: com4j.
>
> ComException: 80029c4a LoadTypeLib failed : 
> Error loading type library/DLL. : .\com4j.cpp:395
>         at com4j.Native.loadTypeLibrary(Native Method)
>         at com4j.COM4J$2.call(COM4J.java:324)
>         at com4j.COM4J$2.call(COM4J.java:322)
>         at com4j.Task.invoke(Task.java:51)
>         at com4j.ComThread.run0(ComThread.java:153)
>         at com4j.ComThread.run(ComThread.java:134)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

JAR files contain Java .class byte code.  DLL contain Windows compiled code.

The only way I can think of to reuse a DLL in Java is to call it using JNI interface.  I'm not sure you can execute native code on Android.   Is JNI allowed on mobile devices?

Comment: we don't have the source code .Instead the dll file is only present.

Comment: Then I have no idea what you expect to be able to do.  JNI is your only hope.    http://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/sample_hellojni.html